# Overridden or Uses a deprecated API?

Tags: java

Here is the code which I've used to calculate the factorial of a number using two threads.
When I try to compile this, it says '....' uses or overrides a deprecated API, someone please help, solve this.

```
import java.lang.Thread;
import java.util.Scanner;

class A extends Thread
{
    int n;
    int fact=1;
    int i;
    A(int x)
    {
        n=x;
        i=n;
    }
    public void run()
    {
        if(i>0)
        {
            fact=fact*i;
            i--;
        }
        else
            System.out.print(fact);
            suspend();
    }
}

class B extends Thread
{
    int i;
    int n;
    int fact=1;
    B(int x)
    {
        n=x;
        i=n;
    }
    public void run()
    {
        if(i>0)
        {
            fact=fact*i;
            i--;
        }
        else
            System.out.print(fact);
            suspend();
    }
}

class refact
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int n;
        System.out.print("Enter the number you want :");
        Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);
        n=a.nextInt();
        System.out.print("\n\n");
        A newthreadA = new A(n);
        newthreadA.start();
        B newthreadB = new B(n);
        newthreadB.start();
    }
}
```

Also, if anyone else has a better idea to calculate factorial of a number using two threads please mention.
Thanks!

Comment: Why are you `suspend`ing the thread?

Comment: Is there something specific that each thread is supposed to do? A specific way for the threads to divide the work? Or can you just have thread 1 calculate the factorial while thread 2 prints encouraging messages? "Go, thread 1! You can do it!"

Comment: You do realise that `run()` only runs once per call to `start()`, right?  It doesn't run over and over until something makes it stop.

Comment: @user2357112 I'm suspending it, assuming that when the number counter reaches 0, it finishes the program.

Comment: @DavidWallace Oh, so how else would I print the factorial of a number using 2 threads?

Comment: You don't need to suspend a thread when there's no more work for it to do.  When a thread reaches the end of the `run()` method, it just stops.

Comment: I don't know why you want to use two threads.  But if you absolutely had to, you could do something like multiply all the odd numbers together in one thread, all the even numbers in the other, then multiply the two final products at the end.  But I don't imagine it helping very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting the error because Thread.suspend is deprecated. Here is more info from the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html):

> **Why are Thread.suspend and Thread.resume deprecated?**
>
> Thread.suspend is inherently deadlock-prone. If the target thread
>   holds a lock on the monitor protecting a critical system resource when
>   it is suspended, no thread can access this resource until the target
>   thread is resumed. If the thread that would resume the target thread
>   attempts to lock this monitor prior to calling resume, deadlock
>   results. Such deadlocks typically manifest themselves as "frozen"
>   processes.

Answer (score 1):

Here you are using suspend() which is deprecated in Java.

Try this use any boolean variable like `executing` to stop thread.

```
public void run() {
        this.executing= true;
        while (this.executing) {
            try {
                //code of factorial
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                this.executing= false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Does executing require another package import?
Because it says 'cannot find symbol'